# Visual Studio Code - Failed to start the kernel - Unable to start Kernel 'Python 3' due to connection timeout

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter, connection-timeout

I am using Visual Studio Code and each time I run a code, it says:

```
connecting to kernel: python 3: activating python environment 'c:\users.....'
```

After this, it then comes up with an error code.

```
Failed to start the kernel - Unable to start Kernel 'Python 3' due to connection timeout
```

I've tried reinstalling Visual Studio Code and also reinstalled jupyter but nothing has worked. It's been a day or two.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. It's not really clear what you're asking. Are you just looking for some way to run your code in VSCode? Cause you don't need to use Jupyter; you could use the debug mode (even without debugging) or use the Code Runner extension. If you do want to use Jupyter, have you tried troubleshooting other parts of your setup? For example, are you connecting to the right Jupyter server? (I assume it's remote cause of the "connection timeout".) Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: docs: [Jupyter Notebooks in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks), [Debug: Run (Start Without Debugging)](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_run-mode)

Comment: Create a new python environment using venv or conda and use jupyter in the new environment. If it still fails, try to update jupyter with the command `pip install jupyter --upgrade`